How does Langchain AgentExecutor serving model LLM?
I followed this tutorial
I conducted some changes:

I built model gemma:2b from Ollama

built Ollama by docker


I used this model replace with ChatOpenAI


Summary

steps/index_generator.py


2.  steps/agent_creator.py


After ran successfully pipeline, it created a agent:


I want to use this agent to serving question/answer service
Here's what I tried in another python
from zenml import step, pipeline
from zenml.client import Client

client = Client()

agent = Client().get_artifact_version('86cb0da2-ca22-48ec-9548-410ccb073bc2') # type(agent) is langchain.agents.agent.AgentExecutor

question = "Hi!"

agent.run({"input": question,"chat_history": []})

it raised the error, How can I overcome this
OllamaEndpointNotFoundError: Ollama call failed with status code 404. Maybe your model is not found and you should 
pull the model with `ollama pull llama2`.

Update
I can interact with gemma model via cli


Huhu, anyone is here?

Did you pull the gemma model and run in Ollama using it's CLI like "ollama run gemma:2b" ? More information can be found here https://github.com/ollama/ollama

I mentioned it, "I built model gemma:2b from Ollama locally"

For the mentioned error, looks like the model is not up in Ollama. Please check and confirm that you are able to invoke the model outside your Agent code.

@SubashKunjupillai Sure, I invoked the model outside
